# FFMpeg Command work in command line, but in python script the image is blueish? (Semi Solved)

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg

Okay, kind of a weird problem.  But I'm not sure whether it's python, ffmpeg, or some stupid thing I'm doing wrong.

I'm trying to take a video, and take 1 frame a second, and output that frame to an image.  Right now, if i use the command line with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i test.avi -r 1 -f image2 image-%3d.jpeg -pix_fmt rgb24 -vcodec rawrvideo
```

It outputs about 10 images, the images look fine, awesome.  Now I have this code (right now some code from some github, as I wanted stuff that i was relatively sure would work, and mine is allll convoluted)

```
import subprocess as sp
import numpy as np
import re
import cv2
import time

FFMPEG_BIN = r'ffmpeg.exe'
INPUT_VID = 'test.avi'

def getInfo():
    command = [FFMPEG_BIN,'-i', INPUT_VID, '-']
    pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
    pipe.stdout.readline()
    pipe.terminate()
    infos = pipe.stderr.read()
    infos_list = infos.split('\r\n')
    res = re.search(' \d+x\d+ ',infos)
    res = [int(x) for x in res.group(0).split('x')]
    return res
res = getInfo()
command = [ FFMPEG_BIN,
        '-i', INPUT_VID,
        '-f', 'image2pipe',
        '-pix_fmt', 'rgb24',
        '-vcodec', 'rawvideo', '-']
pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdout = sp.PIPE, bufsize=10**8)
n = 0
im2 = []
try:
    mog = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG2(120,2,True)
    while True:
        raw_image = pipe.stdout.read(res[0]*res[1]*3)
        # transform the byte read into a numpy array
        image =  np.fromstring(raw_image, dtype='uint8')
        image = image.reshape((res[1],res[0],3))
        rgbImg = image.copy()

        fname = ('_tmp%03d.png'%time.time())
        cv2.imwrite(fname, rgbImg)
        # throw away the data in the pipe's buffer.
        #pipe.stdout.flush()
        n += 1
        print n
except:
    print 'done',n
    pipe.kill()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I run this, I get 10 images, but they all have a Blue Tint!  I cannot for the life of me figure out why.  I've done tons of searches, I've tried quite a few different codecs (usually just messes things up worse).  The media info for the video file is here:

```
 General
 Complete name                            : test.avi
Format                                   : AVI
Format/Info                              : Audio Video Interleave
File size                                : 85.0 KiB
Duration                                 : 133ms
Overall bit rate                         : 5 235 Kbps

Video
ID                                       : 0
Format                                   : JPEG
Codec ID                                 : MJPG
Duration                                 : 133ms
Bit rate                                 : 1 240 Kbps
Width                                    : 640 pixels
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate                               : 30.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:2
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.135
Stream size                              : 20.1 KiB (24%)
```

Any suggestions?  It seems like it should be an RGB mixup...just not sure where at...

EDIT: So I fixed the problem by switching the blue and red channels with this code:
                bChannel = rgbImg[:,:,0]
                rChannel = rgbImg[:,:,2]
                gChannel = rgbImg[:,:,1]

```
            rgbArray = np.zeros((res[1],res[0],3), 'uint8')
            rgbArray[...,0] = rChannel
            rgbArray[...,1] = gChannel
            rgbArray[...,2] = bChannel
```

So I guess this is now a question of, why is python mixing up these channels?  Is it a problem with python, or ffmpeg, the codec?

Thanks!

Comment: opencv uses bgr images , not rgb ones. try to change your ffmpeg format string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

openCV uses BGR instead of RGB for some weird reason.  Have to switch around the pixels to get the correct colours.